# pgfplot connects first and last point of line in the surf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm plotting a surface from data file arranged in columns x,y and value. The result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, first and last point of every line is connected.
Relevant code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
]%
\addplot3[%
surf] table[x index= 0,y index = 1,z index = 2, col sep=tab] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there any way to fix this?